# How can I change my attitude towards my colleagues and my carreer?

Tags: software-industry, communication, colleagues, career-development, unprofessional-behavior

I just read [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/437921/how-to-favor-quick-and-dirty-over-clean-and-slow-in-practice) and it hit hard.

I'm in  a small team of developers (mostly RPA, general AI, and scripting in VBScript, Python, PowerShell and so forth and so on), some of them don't consider themselves developers at all and I'm the only one with a programming background (this means that almost all the scripting tasks are done by me, I also work on RPA), and I'm constantly sad about the state of the art. I'm distressed by it to the point that I feel like crying and that I feel that I've no one to reach among my peers. I know the fault is on me, I'm bad at communicating with the team, I hate attempts to 'connect' only to ask for  something (E.g.: Ehy? How are you? I was wondering can you check this and do that... *why isn't people upfront? This makes me unreasonably angry and I would love to shut my computer down upon reading their bot-like attempt to form a weak bond in order to "get things done"*) , I despise formality on the job, rules that I see as pointless and aren't explained to me and timelines given with no feedback and I hate that most of what I hate about coding practices is present in the question I linked. This made me grumpy and I was unwittingly looking to piss people off with my grumpiness.

I'm feel like I'm in a dark place psychologically, at the moment, and maybe that's why I'm fixated on these issues, however part of these feelings stems from the discussions we have around best practices and the importance of our job and how I feel about programming, our niche, and so on. When I voice  my opinions I'm often met with "poignant" criticism such as "we do what customers asked", "we'll do {this} in the future maybe, there's no need to worry", "there's no time for analisys and requirements, start the project", "we aren't Amazon", and so on. With such critiques, no code-review and reports, code bases, and more that I'm the only to read, my work feels pointless and it feels like I'm only needed if there's an issue with something that they can't solve on their own. How can I grow? In these years I used a lot of technologies and a lot of programming languages but all them "unsupervised", I was the one looking for best practices and so on, the management only cared to "finish" the projects with all means necessary and all my efforts to became a better software engineer were blocked by:

1. The management, which thinks that I should only do stuff as fast as possible without bugging the customer during the development phase, questioning customer's decisions is forbidden, work-arounds are preferred.
2. The colleagues, which think that my efforts to align our knowledge and follow best practices are an act against them and their freedom for some reason and that using basic patterns is "complicating things" and losing time. Most of the time they prefer the least effort solution even if it's clearly the wrong path and they aknowledge it.

I feel like I don't want to go to work anymore, nor going out in general and my daily routine beyond working is completely gone for good. I'm not saying I won't go to work, I have to pay the bills, but day by day I feel deeply sad and I don't know how to act or what do do.

Comment: If you're not enjoying your current job, there is one very obvious answer. What is stopping you going and finding another job?

Comment: @PhilipKendall I think my job can be improved, I like my job in principle, I don't like how I'm forced to do my job, my colleagues aren't bad actors, I bought a house and I need to pay for it and I need to pay the bills.

Comment: Without buy-in from management, which it very sounds like you don't have, your job isn't going to change.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I like my colleagues, I've no reason to hate them. I think they are good people, they just happen to be very different and I often feel like they feel the urge to "compete", generally, an attitude I find ironic at most.

Comment: It sounds you're complaining about this problem as well https://nohello.net/en/ https://www.nohello.com/

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I am! The blogger channeled my inner feelings.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things you can do to improve your situation:

1. Therapy. Number 1 because you can't fix anything else before you fix your mental health.
2. As the only person with a programming background: implement the things you are missing. Feel free to ask forgiveness rather than permission, as it's highly unlikely your superiors will 'get it' until they see it in action.
3. Use a ticket system. You say you hate formalities and so forth. A ticket system will help you bypass all of that and help you manage your workload. Again, forgiveness, not permission.
4. Certifications, if you can afford them. This will help solidify the progress you've made.
5. If all else fails, it's CV time. Don't worry about lack of formal training when applying, experience is often worth more.

Comment: Therapy and find something outside your work to focus on. Your Job shouldn't define you and when you let that happen it makes this easy.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are in a "dark place" because most of the other programmers in your shop are doing crappy work, then you probably shouldn't be programming. In fact, you probably shouldn't be in any constructive job, because the reality is that most people are hacks. You want to see hack work? Become a machinist and watch how 90% of the other machinists are doing things that are both slipshod AND physically dangerous to themselves and coworkers.

Secondly, it is way more important to get things done, than to adhere to some abstract notion of correctness. What I use to tell the kids who worked for me was: "Get this done as fast as possible, because this is going to get rewritten three times anyway, so the faster you get it done, the faster we can start rewriting it. Don't fall in love with your code, because it is probably going to get deleted when we rewrite everything later."

As a longtime developer, I never saw successful software that was not rewritten. The only software that does not get rewritten is software in failed projects.